# Limitations of Mathjax: Which Latex features does Mathjax not support?

Tags: latex, mathjax

My question is, which Latex features aren't supported by Mathjax? For example, in Latex I can write `$\today$` and it will return the current date. This is not possible in Mathjax.

In KaTeX, a Mathjax alternative, there seem to be more troublesome limitations such as `\overrightarrow{AB}` not working. I was wondering, what the current limitations of Mathjax are, in terms of latex rendering, before using it in a website instead of converting tex equations to png images and inserting those. I have noticed that Wikipedia uses the tex2png approach instead of Mathjax and was wondering whether they just did not want to depend on Mathjax, whether it's not fully supported by all browsers, whether it's too slow, whether the limited feature set of Mathjax is a problem or just legacy?

Comment: A whole bunch... actually, this is probably endless, making this question too broad.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, Mathjax, as its name suggest, supports *mathematics* typesetting for the web and is *not* a web-implementation of general-purpose Latex. Here's what this means most notably feature-wise:

- No tables
- No tikzpictures
- No bibliographies
- No support for units, e.g. `\SI{10}{\hertz}` is not possible (requiring the `siunitx` package in latex)
- No special packages, for example no `\uwave` from package `ulem`

Within the math-world, Mathjax is covering *almost* everything. Here is a list of features that are not supported for mathematics typesetting:

- Items that require the `mathtools` package, for example  `H \xrightharpoondown[under]{over} I\\`.

The other question was, why Wikipedia isn't using Mathjax, but has chosen to convert Equations into a png. I think it's because they already had a working solution when Mathjax got popular and don't really have an incentive to switch to Mathjax. Mathjax especially shines, when you need an out of the box solution for rendering math on the web.